# RISCV : spike pk hello returns Failed to run

Tags: riscv

I am new to both RISCV and Ubuntu(64it) env. Have no idea how to solve this problem.
I built the RISCV toolchain and could compile hello.c by using the command "riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -o hello hello.c" The hello object file is sucessfully generated.

However, when I executed "spike pk hello" it returns 
"Failed to run : No such file or directory
 Child dts process failed"

I thought there is something to do with path. So, I went to riscv/bin/ where spike is located and executed "./spike", it gives me exactly the same result.

What would you suggest ? I am totally stuck......

Answer (score 2):

You should install dtc. Use "sudo apt-get install device-tree-compiler"

After installing that package, you will unfortunately have to rebuild the toolchain to get it to notice that it was installed.

Comment: You mean the cross-compiler or the spike simulator or spike-pk? Which part need to be rebuild?